# How to avoid google map break on print preview?

Tags: javascript, css

How to avoid google map break on the print preview?

Tried with below code snippet but it's not working.

```
@media print{
 map{
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have other code you can post showing your HTML tags. The CSS alone does not give the full context.

Comment: I absolutely agree with @JairusMartin. You should provide more code. I cannot comprehend how some people marked this question as OK. From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/26226229).